# How to call a helper method from routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Normally we called a controller method from route like below

```
Route::get('/route_name', 'controllerName@method');
```

But is there any way to call a helper method from route ?

Comment: What do you mean by helper method? a helper method for a route ?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route

Comment: @Christophvh...Suppose I have created a custom helper named `testHelper` and this helper has some functions like `test1(),test2()`...Now I wan to call this `test1()` function from route.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** First one is pretty easy and straightforward. Simply go to composer.json file located in your Laravel project

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

After changing composer.json file and adding a new path to the files array, you need to dump the autoloader. Simply run this command from the terminal in your Laravel project directory.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now your helper file will be automatically loaded in your Laravel project.

**Step 2**
If your helper file involves a class that has those helper methods and you have specified namespace, you could use them with little effort by defining an alias. You can do that easily by adding the following at the end of the aliases array in config/app.php file.

in alias write `'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,`

**Step 3** Now in your web.php you can use helper function

```
Route::post('/area/getAreaList', function() {   
    Helper::getAreas();
})->name('area.getAreaList');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [use a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#basic-routing):

```
Route::get('/route_name', function() {
    helper();
});
```

But a better way to do this is to call a controller method and call the helper from that method:

```
Route::get('/route_name', 'controllerName@methodWhichWillCallHelper');
```