# How to use a function from helper in routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I have a function in helpers.php, which I use in any blade to check if the admin has permission to view some buttons, and it also works in Controllers, but it's not working in routes, the routes ignoring it.

```php
function can($permission)
{
    $userCheck = auth()->guard('admin')->check();
    $user = '';

    if ($userCheck === false) {
        return redirect('admin/login');
    } else {
        $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
    }

    if ($user->id === 1) {
        return true;
    }

    $minutes = 5;
    $permissions = Cache::remember('permissions_'.$user->id, $minutes, function () use ($user) {
        return explode(',', $user->permission->permission);
    });

    $permissions = array_flatten($permissions);

    return in_array($permission, $permissions);
}
```

I use it like this in the blade/view.

```php
@if(can('admins'))
    <a href="{{ url(getLocal().'/admin/admins') }}" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
@endif
```

However, routes ignore the function and open all the routes. I use the function in routes like the following. Any ideas?

```php
if (can('admins')) {
    Route::get('home', 'Admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/admins/{id}/edit', 'Admin\AdminController@edit')->name('admins.edit');
}
```

Comment: the routes are defined before the request is dispatched (before the middleware that starts the session and authentication) ... also there is no reason to have conditional routes at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a helper method from routes in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048975/how-to-call-a-helper-method-from-routes-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes don't need to be conditional. Define all the routes you need then you can restrict access to them with something like middleware. You can create a simple middleware that takes a parameter and calls your `can` function in `app/Http/Middleware/CanDoIt.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CanDoIt
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        if (! can($permission)) {
            // redirect to some where else
        }

        // allow the request to pass through
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You can go into `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add your middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` array there:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'check' => \App\Http\Middleware\CanDoIt::class,
];
```

Then you can assign that middleware to your group of routes you want to restrict by `can('admins')`

```
Route::middleware('check:admins')->group(function () {
    Route::get('home', 'Admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/admins/{id}/edit', 'Admin\AdminController@edit')->name('admins.edit');
});
```

I didn't name the middleware `can` as there is probably already a middleware named `can` registered for Authorization.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Middleware - Defining Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#defining-middleware)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Middleware - Middleware Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Comment: This is the most appropriate solution to handle logic before proceeding with the request, the `middleware` approach.